# Were the seismic charges in Attack of the Clone the first use of a delayed sound effect in space?

Tags: star-wars, history-of, attack-of-the-clones, special-effects, sound-effects

In *Attack of the Clones* we have a chase of Obi-Wan Kenobi by Jango Fett through an asteroid field wherein Fett detonates a series of "seismic charges".

The interesting things about the accompanying effect is the long delay between the visual effect and the sound effect.

Now, this is a depiction clearly inspired by a real world effect due to the difference in the speed of travel between light and sound.   (It is readily apparent in the delay between observation of lightning and thunder.)   Putting aside the question of what exactly the sound effect represents in space (It looks like it's supposed result from some kind of matter shockwave):

## Is this the first instance of such an effect in space?

Comment: Is the sound really delayed, or is it just coming from when energy sphere "collapses"?

Comment: @Skooba, well, it's a subtle point.   I would consider any effect where a significant burst of light silently precedes a significant sound to be qualitatively the same for the purpose of the question.    But there could be gray area (what counts as 'significant'?)

Comment: The more I look at this, the more interesting the effect is.   You have flash; quick expansion to a sphere of finite size; collapse of the sphere into a disk; quick and unbounded expansion of the disk along its plane

Comment: No doubt it is an interesting effect.  The more I watch it the more I am convinced the collapse is causing the sound (like when you clap your hands), but it then raises the question why the initial burst did not cause any sound!

Comment: This has always been one of my favorite Star Wars space weapons. The sound effect gave me the impression of what a huge scale explosion was created.

Comment: I don't think it's delayed sound at all.  I think the device emits a wave of silence before its destructive effect reaches the target.  Note that before the main sounds hits, _everything_ goes silent - engine noises, swooshes, all of it.

Comment: What about the [Death Star](https://youtu.be/exZEGox-omA?t=63)? In the special edition you can hear a sound as the blast wave moves past the camera. You could say this sound is moving with the blast.

Comment: @KodosJohnson:  You can still hear the initial explosion in sync with visual.   I don't count this.

Answer (score 4):

The effect appears to have been created specifically for the movie. Attack of the Clones sound designer Ben Burtt has referred to the effect as an "audio black hole." It was inspired by previous sound design techniques and not by a specific effect found in nature.

> I remember in film school a talk I had with an old retired sound editor who said they used to leave a few frames of silence in the track just before a big explosion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Burtt#Sound_designer

Comment: Downvoted.  Nice quote, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Ben Burtt was the sound designer on Attack of the Clones. He created the actual effect described in the OP, and I quoted his inspiration for the sound effect.

Comment: it still doesn't directly answer the question as asked. It is good info though, - you maybe could get away with that citation and changing the answer to be 'no - the effect was invented for this film specifically' (which is what I think you are going for - no?)

Comment: Yes, that is what I was going for. Edited my answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: @Tim - Partial answers need love too...

Comment: Partial answer gets **the full bounty** because no other candidates.